# htaccess to redirect one domain to another only if no parameters are provided?

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess

I have a domain oldexample.com, and I want to redirect users who visit that domain to newexample.com only when no parameters are given. In the case where parameters are supplied with the domain, it should redirect elsewhere - so, oldexample.com/?id=5 should not redirect to newexample.com, rather I want to redirect it to some internal directory in newexample.com, say to newexample.com/dir/5.

Here's a summary of how I want the redirects to work:

```
oldexample.com -> newexample.com
oldexample.com/?id=3 -> newexample.com/dir/3
oldexample.com/index.php?id=6 -> newexample.com/dir/6
```

So how would I write the RewriteRules in htaccess to get this job done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

# for /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldexample.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !id=
RewriteRule ^$ http://newexample.com/ [L,R=301]

# for /?id=###
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldexample.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^(index.php)?$ http://newexample.com/dir/%1? [L,R=301]
```

The last rule matches against `/` and `/index.php`. These rules need to be in the htaccess file in your `oldexampl.com` document root.

Comment: Ok sorry, but I need something like oldexample.com/?i=54 to redirect like this instead: newexample.com/dir/54. I apologise I wasn't more clear initially, I just need it to know how to redirect it that way, and I can accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @hesson Edited answer, you should edit your question because someone's going to look at your question and see this answer and it will make absolutely zero sense.

Comment: Still having trouble, oldexample.com redirects to newexample.com fine but oldexample.com/?id=1 redirects to newexample.com/?id=1, but it shouldn't. By the way, I did replace ^id=([0-9]+) with ^id=(.*) as my id is not necessarily a number. In the last rule , what is ^(index.php)?$, I don't understand that. Thanks.

Comment: @hesson Ah, it's because first rule was being applied, I added a condition to the first rule

Comment: Thanks, it works. One thing though oldexample.com/?id=1 redirects to newexample.com/dir/1/?id=1 which is fine but it would look a lot cleaner without that useless parameter at the end. Can anything be done about that?

Comment: Actually, I was forgetting the "?" at the end of the last rule, it works perfectly now! Thanks a bunch!!